# How to set noapic and pnpbios=off parameters for boot

Tags: 12.04, boot, bootloader, grub-legacy

I have a weird laptop, that, long story short, must have these 2 parameters set for it to boot:

```
pnpbios=off
noapic
```

How to I tell grub to utilize these every time it boots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit your GRUB configuration file e.g. using the command

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Add those two parameters to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, so that it looks like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pnpbios=off noapic"
```

Then update GRUB's configuration using the command

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: any way to temporarily boot into the OS first to set these parameters?

Comment: Boot in recovery mode, `mount -o remount,rw /`, `mount --all`, then follow the above steps.

Comment: @AlcuinArundel No need for recovery mode, you can temporarily set those kernel parameters by editing the GRUB boot entry from the GRUB menu itself. Select the Ubuntu entry in GRUB and press `e`. Then search the line starting with `linux` in the appearing script and insert the two parameters after `quiet splash`. Press `F10` (if I remember correctly) to boot the modified entry.

Comment: I had a VirtualBox VM suffering the dreaded `MP-BIOS BUG 8254 timer not connected` error and `nolapic` (NOT `noapic`) using @ByteCommander's technique did the trick!