# VirtualBox: "Mp-bios bug:8254 timer not connected to io-apic"

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, 22.04

Every time the virtual machine boots up, this error message pops up:

```
VirtualBox: "Mp-bios bug:8254 timer not connected to io-apic"
```

How can I prevent this error when using VirtualBox?

Answer (score 1):

So far I've disabled 'Enable I/O APIC' option in the virtual machine settings and the error does not show.

Comment: Thank you it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In VMbox got to setting -> system -> motherboard there you will find extended features "Disable" all the features. Now start at the boot time press esc after the logo disappear. there you will get 3 options in that select the second option having "recovery" written and your system will work. By this your error "MP-BIOS bug: 8254 timer not connected to IO-APIC kernel panic - not syncing: IO-APIC + timer doesn't work! Boot with apic-debug and send a report. Then try booting with the 'noapic' option." is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to modify the grub startup parameters by including `noapic` in startup:
A good video has been shared by someone here:
[Metasploitable2 kernal panic - not syncing: IO-APIC error solution (Virtualbox)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYxfhMrjVhk)

The above mentioned method is not permanent solution because it may needs to be performed at each startup. If this is required to be made permanent then this link has given a suitable procedure for it:
[How to set noapic and pnpbios=off parameters for boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801554/how-to-set-noapic-and-pnpbios-off-parameters-for-boot)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).